# Find missing rows from table through a many to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

`user` table:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| user_id | username            |
+---------+---------------------+
|    1136 | 007                 |
|     978 | 11zep11the11hyerian |
|    1049 | 123456789           |
+---------+---------------------+
```

`setting` table:

```
+------------+----------------+
| setting_id | identifier     |
+------------+----------------+
|          1 | email-on-like  |
|          2 | email-on-reply |
|          3 | share-on-vote  |
+------------+----------------+
```

and `user_setting` table:

```
+-----------------+---------+------------+-------+
| user_setting_id | user_id | setting_id | value |
+-----------------+---------+------------+-------+
|               6 |      49 |          2 | 1     |
|               8 |      53 |          2 | 1     |
|               9 |      54 |          1 | 1     |
+-----------------+---------+------------+-------+
```

The `setting` table represents the available settings a user can have against their account. The `user_setting` table is where those settings are saved. Sometimes a new setting is added to the `setting` table and basically I want to create a query which will reflect the missing rows in the `user_setting` table so I can insert them accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you where looking for the missing settings for a single user you have the following two options:

```
SELECT s.setting_id
FROM setting AS s
WHERE s.setting_id NOT IN (SELECT us.setting_id FROM user_setting AS us WHERE us.user_id = ? )
```

or on Oracle:

```
SELECT s.setting_id FROM setting s
MINUS
SELECT us.setting_id FROM user_setting us WHERE us.user_id = ?
```

So, you *could* loop over the records in your user table, and then do this for each record.

Alternatively you can expand these two methods to include the user table by learning to love the cartesian join.  I have to admit that I'm not mysql expert (I'm an Oracle boy), so I'll try my best for you.

**A cartesian join is a join between two tables (or result sets) where every record in one should join to every record in the other.**  That is, there does not need to be an explicit relationship between the tables.

In your case, a cartesian join between user and setting would give you an exhaustive list of all the possible combinations between user and setting regardless of if a setting exists in your join table.

The join to give you all possible setting and user combinations would be (on mysql):

SELECT u.user_id, s.setting_id
  FROM user AS u
  CROSS JOIN setting AS s

The two above SQL staments then change to:

```
SELECT u.user_id, s.setting_id
FROM user AS u
CROSS JOIN setting AS s
WHERE (u.user_id, s.setting_id ) NOT IN (SELECT us.user_id, us.setting_id
                                         FROM user_setting AS us)
```

Or (as an alternative on Oracle)

```
SELECT u.user_id, s.setting_id
FROM user u, setting s
MINUS
SELECT us.user_id, us.setting_id
FROM user_setting us
```

Forgive me if my mysql syntax isn't spot on...

Comment: Yes but it needs to get its rows from the `user` table as there may not be any records for a specific user in the `user_setting` table

Comment: These queries are using bogus joins

Comment: @popovitsj Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Perhaps you meant NATURAL JOIN

Comment: No - I meant "cartesian join" - or "cross join" as it appears to be  known in mysql.  Pretty much the opposite of a natural join.  A natural join as an exactly equals join - a cartesian join is an "I don't care if you even have common data in your definitions" join.  Updating my answer again to clarify.

Comment: You're right, I misread your query. It still has ambiguously defined columns though.

Comment: @RobBaillie MySQL has not implemented `EXCEPT` (or `MINUS` as it is called in Oracle.) You should have to use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` or a `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` construction.

Comment: Apologies - in don't run mysql at all. I'll amend to fix the ambiguous columns and make it clear regarding the MINUS construction

Comment: Updated. Do you now have a clear answer to your question and a deeper understanding of the solution?

Answer (score -1):

Thinking a little bit beyond your actual question, I'd say this is what you want:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_user_settings
AFTER INSERT ON setting
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO user_settting (setting_id,user_id)
  SELECT new.setting_id, u.user_id FROM user u;
END;
```

Comment: Do everything you can to avoid triggers.  One or two seem to solve your problems in elegant and simple ways.  But then very quickly you get to 200 and you have a nightmare spaghetti of cascading triggers that mutate and error and are a nightmare to debug.  Triggers are the enemy of maintainable databases!

Comment: That seems very opinion based.

Comment: Agreed, and normally I'd be very reticent to state an opinion on SO - but this is an opinion based on 15 years of experience building enterprise scale database applications with and without triggers.  Honestly - triggers are like global variables for databases.